# RESTAPI body parameters are passed null when calling in c#

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, rest, service

I am trying to call a rest api method from c#. Problem is for all content types it passes null to body parameter.I shared my code below.Apart from this code I have tried to write body parameter to request as stream.It didn't work either. I have also tried 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' as content type.

Calling rest api method from c# sample:

```
        string token = Server.UrlEncode("v0WE/49uN1/voNwVA1Mb0MiMrMHjFunE2KgH3keKlIqei3b77BzTmsk9OIREken1hO9guP3qd4ipCBQeBO4jiQ==");
        string url = "http://localhost:2323/api/Applications/StartProcess?token=" + token;
        string data =  @"{""ProcessParameters"": [{ ""Name"":""flowStarter"",""Value"": ""Waffles"" }],
                         ""Process"": ""RESTAPISUB""}";

        System.Net.Http.HttpClient client = new System.Net.Http.HttpClient();
        client.BaseAddress = new System.Uri(url);
        byte[] cred = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("username:password");
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", Convert.ToBase64String(cred));
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

        System.Net.Http.HttpContent content = new StringContent(data, UTF8Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
        HttpResponseMessage messge = client.PostAsync(url, content).Result;
        string description = string.Empty;
        if (messge.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            string result = messge.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
            description = result;
        }
```

Rest api Method:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ActionName("StartProcess")]
    public int StartProcess([FromUri]string token,[FromBody]WorkflowStartParameters parameters)
    {
        try
        {
            LoginInformation info = CasheProcesses.ReadCashe(token);
            eBAWSAPI api = Service.GetWSService();
            WorkflowProcess proc = api.StartProcess(info.Id, info.Password, info.ImpersonateUserId, info.Language, parameters);

            return proc.ProcessId;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new Exception("An error occured when starting process,exception detail:" + ex);
        }
    }
```

WorkflowStartParameters class structure:

```
    public class WorkflowStartParameters
    {
        public WorkflowParameter[] ProcessParameters;
        public string Process { get; set; }
    }
    public class WorkflowParameter
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Value { get; set; }
    }
```

I have searched this problem a lot. It seems as a very common problem. I just found this solution working properly, passing request parameter to rest api method and reading body parameter from there. But it is not a valid solution for me.

If you have any idea,feel free to share.

Thanks,
Zehra

Comment: Can you update your question and show what this object looks like: WorkflowStartParameters? My guess is what you are sending cannot serialize back into that type. Also you should look into parsing your object into json with something like NewtonSoft.Json (there is a nuget pckage for it if you don't already have it).

Comment: does naming matter?  you have `WorkflowParameter` in data and `WorkflowParameters` as param.. what happens if you just leave off the `WorkflowParameter` from data and just pass the fields

Comment: @StephenBrickner thanks for reply, I think serializing is the exact problem because when i send body parameters as string it works fine.But I have tried sending serialized data it is passed still null for complex types.By the way I have added WorkflowStartParameters class structure to my question.

Comment: @JamieD77 yes it is an option but there is so many complex body parameter type in our rest api service. I should solve this problem to use the others :|

Comment: I added an answer below. You need to take a look at your ProcessParameters property. Currently it is a field, not a property so you will not be able to deserialize the json back into your object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I have achieved to send filled out data to server. It was about serialization problem. But it didn't work with json serialization before send data. I have added DataContract attribute to my class and it works properly.

Unfortunately still I couldn't figure out this when I make ajax calls from java script it works without DataContract attribute but if I call it in c# it needs DataContract attribute. If someone share the information about this I would appreciate!

I am sharing new class structure, everything else but this still same:

```
    [Serializable]
    [DataContract]
    public class WorkflowParameter
    {
        [DataMember]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string Value { get; set; }
    }

    [Serializable]
    [DataContract]
    public class WorkflowStartParameters
    {
        [DataMember]
        public WorkflowParameter[] ProcessParameters { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string Process { get; set; }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I don´t know if it can solve your problem, but let me try.
I guess you don´t have to utilize Server.UrlEncode in your call, but:

```
  Dim myUri As New Uri(Token)
```

And I guess you must not encode also your username and password - try pass them as string.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem appear to be here:

```
public class WorkflowStartParameters
{
   public WorkflowParameter[] ProcessParameters; <---- needs get/set
   public string Process { get; set; }
}
```

This needs to be a public property to serialize properly. Currently you have it set up as a public field. Just add { get; set; } and give that a try. I would also look into serializing with Newtonsoft.Json to ensure your object is properly serialized. Trying to do it with escape strings will be messing the more data you are sending.

By the way there can be issues sometimes serializing arrays, I would change that to :

```
public List<WorkflowParameter> ProcessParameters{get;set;}
```